# maven Сбилось значение переменной PATH на MAC

Tags: maven, отладка, mac

У меня тут maven сломался (раньше все работало) когда я пишу:

> export
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home

Он работает а когда перезапускаю терминал опять пишет:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Какая команда на Mac, установит это значение на постоянной основе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `export` устанавливает переменные среды только на время текущей сессии. Для добавления на постоянной основе используйте файл `.bash_profile`

Обычно он лежит в директории `$HOME`

```
ls -a $HOME/ | grep .bash

.bash_history
.bash_profile
.bash_sessions
```

Если его нет, просто создайте пустой файл командой `touch`

```
cd $HOME
touch .bash_profile
```

И добавьте в него нужные Вам переменные среды, например:

```
export BOOST_ROOT=/Users/Vladimir/Downloads/boost_1_61_0
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Что бы изменения вступили в силу незамедлительно исполните команду `source` или перезапустите терминал

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло...